# Trace user history in Google Webmaster Tools

Tags: google-search-console

I have more than one user for a website in Google Webmaster Tools.

How can I trace the history of user actions such as "Remove URLs" and so on?

Answer (score 4):

That's not possible (you see URL removals in the account, but you don't see the associated accounts).